# is my aspx page fast?

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to determine how much time it takes for the server to render an aspx page. For now, I'm using my laptop to build the application and the data access is done through linq-to-sql.

1) How does the stopwatch work? 2) Given that it's running on my laptop and that I'm the only user, when I'll implement the stopwatch, what sort of time would be considered fast/slow/acceptable to generate a webpage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all relative. It will be faster if the content is smaller. It will be faster if all content comes from the same place (less content coming from other files). It will be faster if the data is in a static page instead of being loaded from a database.

About all you can do is try and optimize each part of your application as much as is reasonably possible. (Unfortunately, link-to-SQL may not be the most efficient but that's a decision you'll need to make.)

There is no absolute value as far as how long a page should take to render.